# Prove $a^{7}|s$ using induction

Tags: proof-writing, induction

Definition: a positive integer $s$, is 7-free if $a \in \mathbb{N}$, with $a^{7}|s$, then $a=1$. For example, 1, 4 are 7-free. 384 is not7-free.

How can I prove for any integer $m>1$, there exists positive integers, $s$ and $t$ such that $m=st^{7}$ and s is 7-free.

I think Induction would work here? What if I strongly induct? Can I use the definition of 7-free and convert it into gcd? For example, $gcd(a^{7},s)=1$?

Comment: Try writing the unique prime factorization $m = \prod p_i^{\alpha_i}$ and think of how you can remove anything bigger than $7$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Strong induction** hint: if $m$ is 7-free, write $s = m$ and $t = 1$.

If $m$ is not 7-free, find some $a > 1$ such that $a^7 \mid m$. Use the induction hypothesis on $\dfrac m {a^7}$.

Comment: Could u explain a bit more? I'm stuck on the inductive step

Comment: The induction hypothesis is: all numbers from $1$ to $m-1$ can be expressed as $st^7$. Now if $m$ is not 7-free, $m/a^7$ can be expressed as $st^7$, where $s$ is 7-free. How can you express $m$ as $s't'^7$ then? (This proof is also very similar to the proof of existence of prime factorization of an integer)